# The dropdown menu does not open

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, navbar

I build a navbar by bootstrap and I got a problem with the dropdown menu.

 The first:

 1. For now it does not open.

 2. And i want the text inside the dropdown menu will be at right.

 here is the full code of the navbar:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>דף הבית</title>
    <style>
        @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
            .img {
                position: relative;
                top: -50px;
                left: -40px;
            }
        }
    </style>

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

        <!--JQuery.min.js------------>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <!--JQuery.min.js------------>


        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar"
                       aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"/>
                    <span class="icon-bar"/>
                    <span class="icon-bar"/>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active navbar-right">
                        <a href="index.html">דף הבית</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navbar-right">
                        <a href="about_me.html">אודות</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navbar-right">
                        <a href="contact.html">צור קשר</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown navbar-right">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                          aria-expanded="false">
                            לקוחותינו
                            <span class="caret"/>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">דואר ישראל</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">בנק הפועלים</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">בנק לאומי</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"/>
                            <li class="dropdown-header">עבודות מוכנות</li>
                            <li><a href="#">זובי</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">עוד זובי</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="חיפוש">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">חפש</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your icon toggle buttons are not closed `<span class="icon-bar"></span>` and see CSS for adjusting the text to the right.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-default .dropdown-menu > li {
    text-align: right;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .img {
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
    left: -40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active navbar-right"> <a href="index.html">דף הבית</a>

        </li>
        <li class="navbar-right"> <a href="about_me.html">אודות</a>

        </li>
        <li class="navbar-right"> <a href="contact.html">צור קשר</a>

        </li>
        <li class="dropdown navbar-right"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            לקוחותינו
                            <span class="caret"/>
                        </a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">דואר ישראל</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">בנק הפועלים</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">בנק לאומי</a>

            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider" />
            <li class="dropdown-header">עבודות מוכנות</li>
            <li><a href="#">זובי</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">עוד זובי</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="חיפוש">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">חפש</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!. I have a new question, can i ask here or i need to open a new question?

Comment: No problem! If it solved your issue please mark it as answered so others can benefit from it.

Comment: Marked as answered . How can I ask a new question now?

Comment: You should post a new question just as you posted this one originally.